# Is there any way to batch insert sqls read from a file into database using jdbctemplate?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jdbctemplate, vertica

I want to batch insert around 50 thousands of records into the vertica database. I am using spring JDBC template in my application, and I have all those sqls saved in a file, I know there is a way to batch insert by injection of parameters like using preparedstatement, but how can batch insert them directly by sqls?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Xiaoyu this my simple example project I am using this project jdbctemplate and sql query

https://github.com/Z-Farrukzada/Mobile-app-MVP-and-Spring-Boot-RestApi/tree/master/RestApiCarMobileAppSpringBoot/src/main/java/com/CarAnnounceRestApi/RestApiCarMobileAppSpringBoot

Comment: Please don't post link only answers. Include the relevant information from the resource linked in the answer itself, so it is usable without the content behind the link.

Comment: Okey Thank you help me

Answer (score 0):

If your SQL statements look like this:

```
INSERT INTO test VALUES ( 1,'Arthur','Dent',           TIMESTAMP '2017-02-05 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ( 2,'Ford','Prefect',          TIMESTAMP '2017-02-05 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ( 3,'Zaphod','Beeblebrox',     TIMESTAMP '2017-02-05 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ( 4,'Tricia','McMillan',       TIMESTAMP '2017-02-05 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ( 5,'Gag','Halfrunt',          TIMESTAMP '2017-02-05 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ( 6,'Prostetnic Vogon','Jeltz',TIMESTAMP '2017-02-05 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ( 7,'Lionel','Prosser',        TIMESTAMP '2017-02-05 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ( 8,'Benji','Mouse',           TIMESTAMP '2017-02-05 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO test VALUES ( 9,'Frankie','Mouse',         TIMESTAMP '2017-02-05 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO test VALUES (10,'Svlad','Cjelli',          TIMESTAMP '2017-02-05 00:00:00');
```

And the file name is `test.sql`, you can search-replace all that is not needed in this file, to make it a load file.

```sh
$ perl -pe 's/INSERT INTO test VALUES \(//; s/TIMESTAMP //; s/\);//;' test.sql >test.csv
```

Then, fire the Sql command:

```
COPY test FROM LOCAL 'test.csv' DELIMITER ',' ENCLOSED BY '''' REJECTMAX 5 EXCEPTIONS '/dev/tty';
-- in Windows: EXCEPTIONS 'NUL'
```